# Powershell foreach syntax error

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am using powershell to read a text file which has text in lines and display items. How do I use **parallel foreach** instead of **foreach**. I tried foreach and it works but foreach parallel syntax  didnt work.

```
$lines = Get-Content myFile.txt | Where {$_ -notmatch '^\s+$'} 
Foreach ($Item in $lines) 
{
$Item 
}

MyFile.Txt

newyork is great 
seattle is cold
florida is hot
```

This is what I tried

```
$lines = Get-Content myFile.txt | Where {$_ -notmatch '^\s+$'} 
      ForEach -Parallel ($Item in $lines)
            {
            $Item
            }
```

Error: -parallel an be used only in workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `ForEach -parallel`, use your code like this:

```
workflow myworkflow{
    $lines = Get-Content myFile.txt | Where {$_ -notmatch '^\s+$'} 
    ForEach -Parallel ($Item in $lines){
        sequence{
            $Item
        }
    }
}
```

Then, call you workflow: `myworkflow`.

Workflow are very useful, here you can find more info:

- [Basics](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/26/powershell-workflows-the-basics/)
- [Restrictions](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions/)

hope it's useful

Comment: Really helpful. What is the use of sequence in this case? even with parallel i see each record displaying one at a time.

Comment: Great! This is definition of the `sequence` keyword: _The Sequence keyword runs commands in sequence within a Parallel script block. The Sequence script block runs in parallel with other commands, but the commands within the sequence script block run sequentially and in the specified order._ Have a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574157(v=ws.11).aspx) for some examples :)